# How to handle back button of Search View in android

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I have Develop an application that have search view in action bar and i got issue when i am do search its filter perfectly but when i am press back button its still showing filter data so my question is what is event of back button of Action Bar Search view.?

[image]

My Code of Search View is

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(Menus.SEARCH));
    searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));
    editSearch = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    editSearch.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(OnQuerySearchView);


 private OnQueryTextListener OnQuerySearchView = new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            listAllContact.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            listAllContact.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        String text = editSearch.getText().toString()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.filter(text);
        return true;
    }

};
```

Filter Method in Adapter

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    propertyList.clear();

    if (charText.length() == 0) {
       propertyList.addAll(arrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {
        for (ContactProperty p : arrayList) {
            if (p.getFriendName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                propertyList.add(p);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add listener for this as :

```
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do whatever you need
            return true; // KEEP IT TO TRUE OR IT DOESN'T OPEN !!
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do whatever you need
            return true; // OR FALSE IF YOU DIDN'T WANT IT TO CLOSE!
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This listener doesn't work for me. Are you using `SearchView` from **Support Library**? I had to use `setOnSearchClickListener` and `setOnCloseListener` as alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56410389/7767664

Comment: it only works if searchview is always expanded (marked as `collapseActionView `)

Answer (score 7):

You only need to put the "collapseActionView" attribute in the menu layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" 
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/> <--this one
</menu>
```

That will give you the functionality you look for all by itself.

Answer (score 5):

This will collapse the search action item when its focus is lost:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    // be sure to use 'setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener()'
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean newViewFocus)
        {
            if (!newViewFocus)
            {
                //Collapse the action item.
                searchItem.collapseActionView();
                //Clear the filter/search query.
                myFilterFunction("");
            }
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This is the only way I've found to successfully collapse the search item action view when hitting the back button.

Comment: This solved my problem with the search action bar having showAsAction set to ifRoom|collapseActionView. None of the other methods have worked, the android.R.id.home didn't get triggered or nothing. Thank you!

Comment: Correct approach for handling back button is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989340/4026686

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;  
        }
    });
```

Comment: This approach is deprecated, here is new one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989340/4026686

Answer (score 1):

In menifest file

For handling back button of Action Bar - Activity declaration part first of all need to define Parent Activity.

Like-

```
        android:name="com.android.unum.ui.SelfServiceActivity"
        android:label="@string/self_service"
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.unum.ui.DashboardActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.android.unum.ui.DashboardActivity" />
```

Edit onOptionsItemSelected method thats inside activity

NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

//public static void navigateUpFromSameTask (Activity sourceActivity)
 //sourceActivity will be finished by this call.

Note: This method should only be used when sourceActivity and the corresponding parent are within the same task.

For More Info :-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html

Like

@Override

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will don't get the direct event of that searchView navigation click, there is an interface of MenuItam, the name is "MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener()". By using this interface you can get expand and collapsed callback.

Use this below snippets code,

```
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```