# how to handle back button of Search View in android

Tags: android, searchview

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(Menus.SEARCH));
searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));
editSearch = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
editSearch.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(OnQuerySearchView);


private OnQueryTextListener OnQuerySearchView = new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            listAllContact.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            listAllContact.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        String text = editSearch.getText().toString()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.filter(text);
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: can you expand on your question?

Comment: Here is link exactly what you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25842354/1878148

Answer (score 27):

If you use **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** as menu item:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

You can handle back button (for expanded state) with:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Write your code here
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation for your answer?

Comment: just put all return to TRUE or else they would not work. Worked and tested. thumbs up @Atetc

Comment: correct answer. really weird for google detaching searchview onclose listener. even on 23+ API

Comment: This is deprecated method, use following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989340/4026686

Answer (score 2):

MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener is now deprecated

use

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using search dialog you can do something like this for Kotlin

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId

    return if (id == R.id.search_button) {
        val searchManager = this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        searchManager.setOnDismissListener {
            // return the activity to the normal state
        }
        // set activity to search state then request search
        onSearchRequested()
    } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a way of doing it -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Write your code here

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Downvote? The question isn't clearly asked and from what I understood, the asker needs to find out how to handle action when back button is pressed and my solution exactly does that.

Comment: you have a point. This is the worse asked question ever. Not a single detail about the problem...

Comment: This is not the answer. The question is about search view's back arrow icon press.