# How to detect SearchView's back button press?

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, android-search

I'm using a single activity to display SearchView as well as to display search results.  The search results is just a subset of items so the search acts as a filter.  Everything seems to work fine except that I can't figure out how to restore all items in the view when a back button of SearchView is clicked on.

Or maybe there is another way to detect when a user navigates from search results to the previous view (which, in my case, is the same view).

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842555/how-to-handle-back-button-of-search-view-in-android

Comment: Matei Radu, Thanks for the link which provides all the info I needed - including expanding on th3pat3I answer.

Comment: @bdristan after I updated my answer I see now that @MateiRadu supplied you with the correct answer for listening to opening/closing the `SearchView`. However I hope my answer still helps as it has somewhat the explanation to why it doesn't work anymore :-)

Comment: @Darwind you should add the link I shared at the bottom of your answer to make it an even more complete solution for future viewers if bdristan wants to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MateiRadu I just did - at least for completeness it helps - it's so irritating to read an answer and you kinda feel you're missing something in the understanding ;-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So looking at the title of your question, you're not sure how to detect when the `SearchView` is being closed and hence you're not able to restore your views to the "normal" state when the `SearchView` is not open anymore.

**Outdated solution as of Android 4.0+**

The (simple) solution is to add a: `SearchView.OnCloseListener` to your `SearchView`, like this:

```
SearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        // This is where you can be notified when the `SearchView` is closed
        // and change your views you see fit.
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

**Updated solution that works in Android 4.0+**

Apparently the `OnCloseListener` is buggy and doesn't work on newer versions of Android (4.0+). See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25758

The solution to this is to use the Support library version of the `SearchView`:

My `onCreateOptionsMenu` looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchView);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, "onMenuItemActionExpand called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, "onMenutItemActionCollapse called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

As to why Google didn't even bothered to write a comment in the documentation I don't know, but it's sad.

**EDIT2**:

Just adding the link which @MateiRadu added in the comments:

[how to handle back button of Search View in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842555/how-to-handle-back-button-of-search-view-in-android)

This also shows how to use the `OnActionExpandListener` instead of the `OnCloseListener`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately onClose() is not being called when SearchView closes.  However, onQueryTextSubmit() and onQueryTextChange() - as suggested  by th3pat3l - do get called.  Ideally I'd like to utilize all three listeners.

Comment: If you have your own SearchView custom class use:                         @Override public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
        super.onActionViewCollapsed();
    }

Comment: MenuItemCompat is now deprecated.
Try MenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener();
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener.html

Comment: **MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener() is deprecated. Solution:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989235/menuitemcompat-setonactionexpandlistener-deprecated

Answer (score 11):

All code here is **deprecated** ! You should use something like this.

```
final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

item.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onMenuItemActionExpand called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onMenutItemActionCollapse called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 4):

Darwind's answer will do the job but that only works when user presses the back button to close the keyboard and when `SearchView` doesn't have focus anymore.

The better way to do it is to listen for `SearchView`'s text changes.
This way you can restore views and control UI as the text is updating.
here's how I do it.

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // this is when user is done typing and clicks search
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // you can use this to do a "live" search while the user is typing.
        // this will trigger each time user changes (adds or removes) text
        // so when newText is empty, restore your views
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

  
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean newViewFocus) {
            if (!newViewFocus) {
                //Collapse the action item.
                searchItem.collapseActionView();
                //Clear the filter/search query.
                myFilterFunction("");
            }
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Use this ,Its helpful

Answer (score -1):

There is one other trick:

```
searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSearchViewShown() {
                    if(!txtToolbarTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        searchView.setQuery(txtToolbarTitle.getText().toString()+ " ", false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                    if(txtToolbarTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thats from a library searchview not from android native searchview