# Action bar back button returning to previous activity on expanded SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, searchview

I've got a SearchView which expands to search automatically when starting an activity, but I want the back button to the left of it to return to the previous activity instead of closing it. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    showExitAlertBox();
}

public void showExitAlertBox() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setMessage("You want to quit the play?");

    //Yes Quit then go to category page
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PREVIOUSACTIVITY.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    });

    //no Quit stay on same page
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", null);
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Not what I wanted, but worked it out with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039511/how-to-detect-searchviews-back-button-press

Comment: What You looking for? if it worked then click the right mark